# jQuery datatables add selected row to second table

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have two tables

First table:

```
var oTable1 = $('#table1').dataTable({
"sAjaxDataProp": "firstDataSource",
...
"aoColumns": [
  { "mData": "name" },
  { "mData": "value" },
]
```

Second table:

```
var oTable2 = $('#table2').dataTable({
"sAjaxDataProp": "secondDataSource",
...
"aoColumns": [
  { "mData": "newName" },
  { "mData": "newValue" },
   {
            "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                return '<a id="addbtn" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href=#/' + full[0] + '>' + 'Add' + '</a>';                
            }
        }
]
```

I need add new row to first table from second table. Whether it is possible to do so? How implement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For implement you can try use this link http://jsfiddle.net/n57ra688/ or http://jsfiddle.net/NpT26/14/
```